# How to make webpack ignore library dependencies?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a node library that I'm developing called 'MyLib' that is compiled to a `dist/my-lib.js` file using the `webpack` command.

Now, I have another project that makes use of that library. I "included" it by doing:

```
npm install --save ../../my-library
```

And in my project's index.js I can do:

```
import { ExportedClass } from 'my-library'

...

const ec = new ExportedClass()
```

So far so good. Now, I make some changes to the lib and include some feature that uses a certain babel config, then I build the library and go back to the main project, but now the main project fails to compile and complains about a missing/disabled babel-loader config? Why?

```
Error in /.../my-library/src/MyClass.js 
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): 
SyntaxError: /.../my-library/src/MyClass.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (17:14)
```

Isn't the purpose of building the other library is to be able to just import and use it? Why do I have to replicate its build env and dependencies in my project?

For context: Both my project and library are built using webpack and in development mode with target: node.